# Video capture on MacOS

Tags: c++, c, macos, opencv

i've a problem with openCV library under MacOs 10.4. When I try to execute this row to save some frame captured from webcam

```
CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(
                             "out.avi", 
                             CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 
                             fps, 
                             imgSize);
```

i can see this on stdrr:

> OpenCV ERROR: Internal error (Cannot
>   create data reference from file name)
>   in function icvCreateVideoWriter,
>   cvcap_qt.cpp(1291) Terminating the
>   application...

Any idea? If I try to save some images it works fine.

thanks to all!
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Does your program have write permissions in the directory you're running from?

Have you tried putting in an absolute address to, say, your home folder?

What happens if you change the file name, or the FourCC code?

Comment: Yes, the program can write in the directory (I can save single frame on JPG)

I've tried to put full path

I don't try with FourCC but, I've to use quicktime (my team leader request)